# How to moq and override constructor?

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

Is it possible to moq and override a constructor with Moq library?

I have a class like this:

```
public class A{
    private string _b;
    public A()
    {
        _b = Service.getB();
    }
    public int duplicate(int a){
       return a*2;
    }
}
```

I want to test method "duplicate", but I cannot instantiate an object of type A, because I'm missing some dependencies. Can I somehow override/mock constructor in order to create an object and use it for testing other methods?

Changes should be applied in test only, **I should not change class A**.

Comment: A better design (subjectively) is to inject your dependancy on Service into the constructor. Then it is much easier to unit test (because you can easily mock `Service.getB()`).

Comment: I assume that there is no solution for case like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no possibility to override or mock constructor using [Moq framework](http://code.google.com/p/moq/).

Even if you try to create `TestA` class and inherit it from `A`, parameterless constructor will be invoked anyway. You can read more in the following article ["Constructors in C#"](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html). There is also a quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> If a class contains no instance constructor declarations, a default
>   instance constructor is automatically provided. That default
>   constructor simply invokes the parameterless constructor of the direct
>   base class. If the direct base class does not have an accessible
>   parameterless instance constructor, a compile-time error occurs.

If it is really needed to override constructor you can have a look at another mocking frameworks (e.g. [TypeMock](http://docs.typemock.com/isolator/Default.aspx##Ref.chm/Documentation/MockingConstructors.htm) can mock even static constructors)

There are [SO question "What C# mocking framework to use?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-sharp-mocking-framework-to-use) with a long list of mocking frameworks and presentation ["Battle of the mocking frameworks"](http://www.slideshare.net/dhelper/battle-of-the-mocking-frameworks) that might help you to choose right tool.

Comment: @argonius if you truly cannot change the class you are trying to test, then this is the best answer. You're going to need a mocking framework that uses reflection to intercept the calls. It will be a much heavier solution than if you could just provide a constructor override to allow injection, but this sounds like it may be your only choice. I feel bad for you. :-D

Answer (score 1):

So what exactly is `Service`? A better design would be to put that in as a parameter to the constructor. Then you can mock/stub that out and be able to test your `duplicate` method without any hard-coded dependencies.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that, but unfortunately I can't modify the class in this case. I just want to know is it possible to test it like this or not.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly what you can do is create a new constructor internal so you can inject the dependencies from the outside (or use any of the dependency injection frameworks)

```
internal A(B b)
{
    _b = b;
}
```

so you don't change your public API for other assemblies, and in your Test assembly add an attribute to assembly.cs

```
[InternalsVisibleTo("YourTestAssembleNamespace.TestClass.dll")]
```

so in your test you would do something like this

```
//bmock = new Mock<IB>();
var A = new A(bmock);
```

Comment: This could be solution if I could change class A, but not in this case

Comment: I don't agree with this solution at all. You should never modify your core code JUST to be testable. You should instead write code with testing in mind, when it makes the best sense in your design and architecture.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Agree with you that the core code should not be modify, but in some cases, if the logic is not changed and only allowing dependency injection (even thoough poor dependency injection) is the change to support testing, this could be a solution

Comment: @EkoostikMartin I also do not subscribe to the theory of do not change your code to be testable. The reality is that there is a lot of code written that is simply not testable, and to have any confidence in what it's doing, sometimes you must refactor (not re-engineer) it to provide that. I think the theory of don't change code to be testable ignores brownfield development and should go into extinction.

Comment: @Damon - so you would comprise the design and clean implimentation of your design just so you could unit test? So you make the software "worse (theoretically)" to unit test at that point. As an extreme example, you make private methods public to make them testable. It's a slippery slope. Btw, I'm not implying to not test at all in this case, you can integration test so mocking is not required.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin, In this specific example, the code isn't cleanly testable and I see no reason (other than the author isn't allowed to) not to change the constructor to allow composition; pass in the collaborator, instead of letting the class go to a Singleton to resolve it. Check out the [warning signs of non-testable code](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/) by Misko Hevery. Also, if you do not have tests around the code and if you're calling a singleton in the constructor, then the implementation is most definitely not clean, and you have no way of proving it is.